# How can I generate random unique temp file names?

Tags: perl

I am trying to create a temp file using the following code:

```
 use File::Temp  ;
 $tmp = File::Temp->new( TEMPLATE => 'tempXXXXX',
                        DIR => 'mydir',
                        SUFFIX => '.dat');
```

This is create the temp file. Because of my permission issue, the other program is not able to write into file.

So I just want to generate the file name without creating the file. Is there any where to do that?

Comment: It just only the file name  and i dont want to create file . Other program will create the filename .  I am looking for get only the file name .

Comment: Just generating the name and using it later creates race conditions: another program (run by a different user) may create the file before you do. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: once i generate the file name i will pass to another program that program wait for mee to get the file and then it will create that file and write what it want .  now program one is creatign file with different permission and program 2 not able to wirte into that file

Comment: So what you are saying is the design of the two programs is fatally flawed.  Your best bet is probably to create the file, [`unlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/funtions/unlink.html) it, and then call the second program, but you will have a race condition.

Comment: Have you ever thought of looking how File::Temp generates its filename? All that code is waiting there for you to read it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't create the file at the same time you create the name then it is possible for the a file with the same name to be created before you create the file manually.  If you need to have a different process open the file, simply close it first:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Temp;

sub get_temp_filename {
    my $fh = File::Temp->new(
        TEMPLATE => 'tempXXXXX',
        DIR      => 'mydir',
        SUFFIX   => '.dat',
    );

    return $fh->filename;
}

my $filename = get_temp_filename();

open my $fh, ">", $filename
    or die "could not open $filename: $!";
```

The best way to handle the permissions problem is to make sure the users that run the two programs are both in the same group.  You can then use [`chmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod.html) to change the permissions inside the first program to allow the second program (or any user in that group) to modify the file:

```
my $filename = get_temp_filename();

chmod 0660, $filename;
```

Comment: Natmaka's comment below is right, in that the file will be deleted when the function returns. For my own need, I am keeping unlink set and I return the filehandle. I am free to close file or not depending on the situation. The file still is deleted when the program exits.

Answer (score 7):

Just to obtain the name of the tempfile you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

use File::Temp qw/tempfile/;

my $file;

(undef, $file) = tempfile('tmpXXXXXX', OPEN=>0);

say $file;
```

But as Chas. Owens said, be careful the same name could be created before you use it.

Answer (score 4):

The get_temp_filename function proposed by Chas. Owens uses a local filehandle object ($fh), which is destroyed upon function return, leading to the created tempfile destruction.

To avoid this, and therefore keep the file (less risk) add:

```
UNLINK => 0
```

to the `new` method arguments, forbidding file unlink at object deletion time.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I agree with Chas.Owens - the design is fatally flawed.

It really feels like you need to fix the design, so:

If you have control of the 2nd program, have **that** program create the filename **and** the file, and pass the filename to the 1st program.

---

But, if the 2nd program isn't something you wrote and so you cannot modify it then I'd recommend one of the following:

1 - Use the first processes PID as part of the file name in an attempt to minimize the risks of duplicate filenames.

2 - Have the 2nd program pipe its output to the 1st program, don't bother with a file at all.  Personally, this is a much better solution than 1.

3 - Wrap the 2nd program in a script (shell, perl, whatever) which creates the name and the file and passes that to both programs.